# casting float vs numeric in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, floating-point, numeric

I have two queries casting the same number of 2 different data types into numeric data type

```
SELECT cast(cast(79.523500 as float) as numeric(20,3))
```

result:- 79.523

```
SELECT cast(cast(79.523500 as numeric(20,6)) as numeric(20,3))
```

result:- 79.524

Why is it 2 different answers for the same number?

Comment: Because `float` is not accurate, only approximate

Comment: The `CAST` rounds to the smallest precision for both. But rounding a float sometimes rounds half down. For example `SELECT round(0.5550E0, 2), round(1.5550E0, 2)` returns `0.56 1.55`. But you can trick it to always round half up by adding a tiny number to it. F.e. `SELECT round(1.5550E0 + 1E-9, 2)` returns `1.56`